# File Tax Refund in Germany - 2016 Tax Declaration Germany and Tax Return

Tags: working-visas, germany, taxes, blue-card

I am married since the beginning of 2016, but just this month my wife joined me.

My Tax category changed from **1** to **3**

How can I get the refund of the whole year as if I was in category 3 from the beginning?

What are the deadlines for filing my request of refund for the year of 2016?

When does the Tax institution or however it is called returns the taxes?

Comment: As I understand it, your new tax category automatically applies for the whole year in which you got married.  Since you've been having money withheld at the rate applicable to tax category 1, however, you will not get that money back until after you file with the Finanzamt.  I don't know what the deadlines are, nor how long the refund generally takes.